# UItabar can not change colour or transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented the code below to make the `tabBar` transparent but its not taking effect at all, is there something I missed out? I have this code in the `UItabbarcontroller`.

```
 mainTabbar.barTintColor = .clear
 mainTabbar.tintColor = .black

 mainTabbar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
 mainTabbar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: please show `mainTabBar` initialization.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Its in Maintabbarcontroller class, then i directly use the code above in viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
func configureTabBar(tabBarController:UITabBarController) {
        //Tab bar customization
        tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = coloredImage(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size, restrictedToRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width),height: (tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)), color: UIColor.clear)
        tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
```

then use this method to create the clear color `UIImage`

```
func coloredImage(size:CGSize,restrictedToRect:CGRect,color:UIColor) -> UIImage{

    let colorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) , size: size))
    colorView.backgroundColor = color
    colorView.contentScaleFactor = UIScreen.main.scale

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(restrictedToRect.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    colorView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

**Example of use**

```
if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        self.configureTabBar(tabBarController: tabBarController)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in UITabbarViewController class

```html
self.tabBar.barTintColor = .clear
self.tabBar.tintColor = .black
```

Comment: the problem is the tab bar does not have any effect taken on no matter what color i use